# Is there a way, I can block HTTP request inside the angular HTTP interceptor until some other request success?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have angular application where API calls (R2,R3..) should be called with certain headers. But data for this headers are fetch from another service call (R1). So we have to block other requests until R1 completes.

Comment: Make use of ``async`` and ``await`` functionality

Answer (score 0):

RxJs Observer can be use in this case. R2 and R3 should be called when response comes from R1. So subscribe observer somewhere and call R2 and R3 on response if header comes. Call observer.next from R1 response.

Comment: Other R2 and R3 call in difference components. So we can't use this.

Comment: R2 and R3 will be called only where observer subscribed and subscribe only where it required. Don't subscribe everywhere.

Comment: You can also pass message with observer.next(message) to identify that which R2 and R3 need to be called.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

- make R1 as an  observable from a BehaviourSubject
- all the calls R2, R3...RX that need these headers subscribe to R1 and wait for completion, then resume

R1 have to be executed once and multicast the next to all its Observers (R2, R3, ...) and the BehaviourSubject replay the last next() to every subscribers that need to be notified

If all your requests are under this requirement (all R requests are dependent from these headers) then is more practical (of course) the use of an HttpInterceptor in combination with an BehaviourSubject. 
Also you can consider extending the httpClient and pipe R1 with the request you are about to create. All depends on your project requirements

Hope this helps